# can i have more than one java application server on one server?

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, jboss, application-server

is it possible to install more than one java application server on one server or VPS ?
i want to install JBOSS , TOMCAT , WEBLOGIC and my be more.
how this is possible and what the benefits and disadvantages ?!

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, if you want to try all of them. You just have to select different port for each services.

Is there a real use-case ? You could have an application bound to your application server, and you could want to run different applications.

Comment: Differnt ports, or better, differnt IP addresses. It's usually worth assigning each app server a different IP address so you can later move it to a different server without having to adapt the service address in all clients.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The usual problem is that a given port can only be used by a single process.

Hence you cannot have both JBoss and Weblogic on port 8080.  Also a lot of extra ports are needed for normal operation.  This is at best tedious.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible. You need to take care about port's these servers use.

Also you need to check what resources (cpu's/core/RAM) you have on your server. Your system should have ample resources to Run multiple servers.

I don't know whats use case, But if possible I would prefer having various webapps on single Java applicationserver.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned above it is possible but it is a configuration management nightmare.

If it is for compatibility testing, I would look at EC2 or similar timebased hosting and , put an 1 app server in 1 image and spin up each image in turn and shut it down after the test is finished.

The money that costs is paid 10x by not having to edit all kind of configuration files and debugging weird conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

**Pros:**

- You don't need extra servers to run your appservers, so you save in physical/virtualmachines. This helps a lot when you're prototyping something, and also in functional testing, because you can share servers between applications.
- Some applications may need incompatible appserver settings, so you must run them in different appservers, side by side.
- Downtime of one appserver doesn't affect other appservers.

**Cons:**

- You must make sure that every appserver gets enough share of CPU, memory, etc.
- You must assign port numbers to each appserver
- You are making each environment's performance dependent on each other's.

So, it is something that you do mainly to experiment/develop/test. In production environments you have to be much more careful when running appservers side by side..